# How to redirect a website if invalid URL path is entered in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp-3.0

I am using PHP version 7 and .htaccess file with Ubuntu operating system

```
www.abc.com/ghfgdfg to www.abc.com
```

Comment: Look into Mod Rewrite .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your .htaccess file.

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /
```

this redirects to all wrong pages to your homepage.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using this site to generate a htaccess:
https://www.htaccessredirect.net/

But to answer your question, you need to put this in your htaccess:

```
Redirect 404 www.abc.com/ghfgdfg www.abc.com
```

Check here [documentation](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file)

Comment: Nice documentation! Thanks